# Apache camel how insert property in SetBody

Tags: apache, apache-camel

I am creating a message in my route, using:

```
    <setBody id="_setBody1">
                        <constant>
<![CDATA[
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&>
    ..........
            <mes:CalendarView MaxEntriesReturned="5" StartDate="(property.DateStart)" EndDate="(property.EndDate)"/>
```

But property doesn't work. In log I see:

```
 <mes:CalendarView MaxEntriesReturned="5" StartDate="(property.DateStart)" EndDate="(property.EndDate)"/>
```

How I can insert property in message?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to set some properties inside a static content of XML. I suggest using one of the templates.. such as velocity. It will allow you to do property replacement and manage the static content outside of the route (which is handy for testing and other maintenance)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i created property before:

```
  <setProperty id="_setProperty1" propertyName="DateStart">
                <groovy>new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(request.body.getStartDate())</groovy>
            </setProperty>
```

But i want to insert this property in content of xml, inside Apache Camel route.